# How to fix: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I'm new to CMake here. I am trying to build a project locally and I keep running into:

```
./boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:15: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#     include <unistd.h>
```

When I run `clang -v` I get:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I tried to run `xcode-select --install` and it still didn't work. Any idea what else I can try? Thanks!

Here is the CMakeLists file: https://github.com/redpanda-data/redpanda/blob/dev/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
# keep this minimal. modify `cmake/main.cmake` file instead
if(NOT VECTORIZED_CMAKE_DIR)
  include(main)
else()
  include(${VECTORIZED_CMAKE_DIR}/main.cmake)
endif()
```

Comment: Are you trying to compile boost itself? If not, did you install a macos distribution of boost or some other distribution?

Comment: I installed boost with: `brew install boost`. For reference this is the project I'm trying to build locally: https://github.com/redpanda-data/redpanda

Comment: Ok, then something is either wrong with that dist because it only tries to include `unistd.h` if `BOOST_HAS_UNISTD_H` is `#define`d - or your build system removes the standard include paths when building. If you do `mdfind -name unistd.h` does it show it?

Comment: If you create a small program containing only `#include <unistd.h>` `int main() {}` and then run `g++ small_program.cpp` - does it fail?

Comment: In either case, show your `CMakeLists.txt` for your project.

Comment: If I do `mdfind` i get:

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/unistd.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/unistd.h`.
Let me try with a small program.

Comment: If I create a small program with `#include <unistd.h>` it doesn't fail. This is the `CMakeLists.txt` of the project I'm trying to build: https://github.com/redpanda-data/redpanda/blob/dev/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Just added the `CMakeLists` code block to the post!

Comment: Ok, that must be a tiny part of some bigger cmake system. It can't give you the output you claim to get on its own.